# Upload new revision file

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Is possible upload an existing file and automatically create a new revisión instead of replace it?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an update (PUT) request, or patch request, you can specify the [newRevision](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/update#newRevision) query parameter to create a new revision.